# Flexbox IE и Edge

Tags: css, вёрстка, internet-explorer, flexbox, microsoft-edge

Сверстан сайт на flexbox. Проблема в том, что во всех браузерах меню нормально и адекватно отображается в одну строку, но в IE и Edge текст в меню съезжает вниз.
Сколько не гуглил - не нашел ничего про такое ни в спецификации ни на просторах интернета.

Код контейнера:

```
ul.main-menu{
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Код элементов:

```
ul.main-menu li{
padding-right: 20px;
position: relative;
}

ul.main-menu li a{
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial;
font-size: 17px;
color: #041e41;
display: inline-block;
-webkit-transition: all ease 0.2s;
transition: all ease 0.2s;
padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

Меню в IE и Edge:
[image: Меню в IE и Edge]

Меню во всех остальных браузерах:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хоть ссылку показал бы ..

Comment: По порядку. Попробовать для ссылки задать `display: block;`, не поможет - вообще убрать. Не поможет - `white-space: nowrap;`. Это так, пальцем в небо, так как ссылки нет.